# What is the imageurl in Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-build

Here https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/building/containers it says

> Run the command: `gcloud builds submit --tag IMAGE_URL`
>
> Replace IMAGE_URL with a reference to the container image, for
> example, gcr.io/myproject/my-image:latest.

What is IMAGE_URL, is it something that I make up or is it something I needed to have created in a previous step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run this command, you ask Cloud Build to build a container based on the Dockerfile of your current environment.

This container needs to be store somewhere. The easiest solution is to use [GCR (Google Container Registry)](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry), a managed service where you can store your container image. You have nothing to create or build. You only have [several base URLs according with your location](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#tag_the_local_image_with_the_registry_name), then, you need to add your projectID and your image name to have this pattern

```
<optional region.>gcr.io/<ProjectID>/<ImageName>
```

If you want to use [artifact registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry), the new container registry of Google Cloud, with more feature and capacity, you have to [create it](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/manage-repos) before being able to [use it](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling). The naming is longer, but allow you to have several repository in the same project, and to set permission on each repository.

---

So, to answer your question

> is it something I needed to have created in a previous step?

It depends what you want to use!